# Fedora Upgrade Error

Tags: fedora, software-installation, upgrade

I was trying to upgrade to Fedora 16 (I had f14) using *preupgrade*. However,
it fails at the end (after saying: *preparing transaction from installation source*) and gives the following error:

*A fatal error occurred when installing the file system package. This could indicate errors when reading the installation media.Installation cannot continue.*

Comment: Might be a faulty DVD. Did you run `mediacheck` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping releases is not allowed. Besides, F16 is EOL. Backup and perform a clean install. What you're trying to do is unsupported, sorry.

Comment: And install Fedora 18, or (if Fedora's release cycle is too fast) consider <http://www.centos.org> for example (clone of RHEL, is handled similarly to Fedora, and has a much longer life).